# Compare property called by name with type T in where clause lambda expression

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

I will start by showing my code :

```
public IEnumerable<MessageSummary> GetMessagesBy<T>(string propertyName, T parameter)
{
            tempMessages = mylist.Where(x => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals((T) (x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(x, null)), parameter)).ToList();
...
}
```

I would like to get a list of object in mylist, depending the property given as parameter, and compare it to an object of variable type.
It breaks on this line, saying that there were a problem in the where clause.

But, if I do this :

```
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals((T)mylist.First().GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(mylist.First(), null), parameter))
{ ... }
```

It works well...

What's wrong in my where clause ?

Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: Which problem did you have in the Where clause? Anyway, the first expression does the job for all the items in `myList`, while the second one does the job only in the first element (`myList.First()`) of collection. Maybe the first element is a particular object that has some properties for which the second expression is valid?

Comment: I tested it with `string` and `int` and it works correctly

Comment: What `T` do you use when you encounter the problem? Does that type allow `null`, and are there any `null` values in `mylist`? Is that type sealed, and are some instances from `mylist` more derived? Maybe you should do `var propInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);` before your Linq expression?

Comment: Humm... according to the Albertos's comment, I tried to do it on my second item, and it does the same problem. I'll check values of my list. thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening, then the generic argument to your method is either a less-derived type of the items in the list, in which case the actual type of the items in the list has the property in question, but whatever type passed as the generic argument does not, or not all of the items in the list are implicitly convertible to the type passed as the generic argument, and so the conversion itself is failing.

The solution would be to ensure that the generic argument passed to the method is in fact the appropriate type.  Or, for that matter, since you already have the `List`, you probably shouldn't even have `GetMessagesBy` be generic in the first place, since you already know what the generic argument of the `List` *actually* is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the iteration. My list was of type IQueryable (forgot to notice it...), and when I tried to access to the second item (for exemple) like that : `mylist.elementAt(1);` it failed.

I just added a .ToList(), and now it works...

```
tempMessages = mylist.ToList().Where(x => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals((T) (x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(x, null)), parameter)).ToList();
```

Thanks for your time and your answers.